# Lightning: Is it possible to link to an Account/Contact "Related Details" tab?

Tags: lightning, hyperlink

Is it possible to link directly to an account / contact's Related Details tab? By default it opens up to the Related tab. I know I can set the default to be the Related Details tab, but I'm wondering if it's possible to simply link to it?

I looked at a similar post ([Link to a record detail page from a Lightning Component](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/147033/link-to-a-record-detail-page-from-a-lightning-component)) but using the `/one/one.app?#/sObject/[id]/view` link doesn't work. Using `/one/one.app?#/sObject/[id]/edit` does open up to the edit page, so I'm just wondering if there's anything similar to open up the Related Details page.

[image]

Here's a screenshot of my page. I want to reload the page on the "Undead" button by performing some logic and then loading the page again: window.parent.location = "/one/one.app?#/sObject/${AccountPage}/view". The current logic only brings me back to the RELATED tab, not the DETAILS tab.

Comment: Can you clarify a bit further on your question? Are you using standard LEX page? As you already mentioned there's an option to default the Detail tab. If that's not the case, then are you looking to redirect at a record detail page from a custom lightning component? More details with any screenshot will help here. You can edit your post to provide further details for someone to be able to assist you.

Comment: @JayantDas thanks for the tip. I'm pretty new to SFDC but my understanding is that the record detail page is pretty much "out of the box". I have an apex+visualforce page that corresponds to a custom field (Status) that when you click on the button provided, will refresh the page. So I'm just trying to find the URL scheme for refreshing the page and landing on the DETAILS tab. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Lightning does not currently support record page deep-linking (i.e. a URL that definitely gets you to a specific sub-tab).

However if you would just like to have it **always** default to the Details tab, what you should do is edit the Lightning App Builder layout for this page and select Details as the default. Save, and activate it as the org-wide default.

Comment: There's now an idea for this https://trailblazer.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=0874V000000U5B8QAK