# Provider type not supported error in Lightning component

Tags: lightning-aura-components

I need to  avoid hardcoding redirection urls. Is it possible?.I reffred below post Still I can able to see hardcod url in the ans:

[Link to a record detail page from a Lightning Component](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/147033/link-to-a-record-detail-page-from-a-lightning-component/147037)

> ```
> <td><lightning:formattedURL value="{!'/one/one.app?#/sObject/'+ userData.Id + 
>          '/view'}" target="_blank" label="{!userData.Name}"/></td>
>                         <td><lightning:formattedURL value="{!'/one/one.app? 
>      #/sObject/'+ userData.Id + '/view'}" target="_blank" label=" 
>          {!userData.User__r.Name}"/></td>
> ```

---

Issue 2:

Lets consider it as different context:

Trying to pass value to one more component.Getting below error:

> This page has an error. You might just need to refresh it. Assertion Failed!: Provider type not supported : false Callback failed: apex://GSS_AddandCloneSkillsExtension/ACTION$getSelectedUserData Failing descriptor: {c:GSS_UserDataDetails}

```
      <aura:attribute name="UserdataList" type="List"/>
      <aura:iteration items="{!v.lstSelectedUserDataRec}" var="userData" >
                    <tr>
                        <c:GSS_UserDataDetails userData="{!userData}"/>

                    </tr>
  </aura:iteration>
```

GSS_UserDataDetails:

```
<aura:component implements="force:appHostable,flexipage:availableForAllPageTypes,flexipage:availableForRecordHome,force:hasRecordId,forceCommunity:availableForAllPageTypes,force:lightningQuickAction" access="global" >
<aura:attribute name="userData" type="GSS_User_Data__c"/>
<td><lightning:formattedURL value="{!'/one/one.app?#/sObject/'+ userData.Id + '/view'}" target="_blank" label="{!userData.Name}"/></td>
<td><lightning:formattedURL value="{!'/one/one.app?#/sObject/'+ userData.Id + '/view'}" target="_blank" label="{!userData.User__r.Name}"/></td>
```

Instead of this Line.

```
   <c:GSS_UserDataDetails userData="{!userData}"/>
```

If I write below Line of code.It will work:

```
  <td><lightning:formattedURL value="{!'/one/one.app?#/sObject/'+ userData.Id + '/view'}" target="_blank" label="{!userData.Name}"/></td>
<td><lightning:formattedURL value="{!'/one/one.app?#/sObject/'+ userData.Id + '/view'}" target="_blank" label="{!userData.User__r.Name}"/></td>
```

Answer (score 1):

## Example 1

You can, and should whenever possible, use the [`<lightning:navigation>`](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning:navigation/documentation) component to generate URLs and manage navigation for you. It does not cover all situations - for example, it doesn't support navigating to a Visualforce page while providing parameters - but it does support navigating to sObject view pages.

`<lightning:navigation>` is a service component, so you declare it in your markup, give it an `aura:id`, and then access it by that ID in JavaScript to call its public methods, `generateUrl()` and `navigate()`.

Both methods take a [`PageReference`](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/components_navigation.htm) object, and that documentation offers more examples than the Component Library linked above in the [`PageReference` Types](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/components_navigation_page_definitions.htm) section. The specific `PageReference` type you want is this sort, for a record page:

```
{    
       "type": "standard__recordPage",
       "attributes": {
           "recordId": "001xx000003XXXXAAG",
           "objectApiName": "Account",
           "actionName": "view"
       }
}
```

Note that this component is available only in `one.app` containers.

## Example 2

```
<td><lightning:formattedURL value="{!'/one/one.app?#/sObject/'+ userData.Id + '/view'}" target="_blank" label="{!userData.Name}"/></td>
```

This isn't valid because it's missing the `v.` value provider to access component attributes. That is the source of the error

> Provider type not supported

Comment: Thanks david.can you please provide code snippet navigation componet refrring to my component

Comment: @AnnappaPH There are extensive examples in the Lightning Component Library, linked in my answer.